# Unable to create maven package for AEM due to use of data-sly-set

Tags: maven, aem

When attempting to create a package for my ui.apps folder with maven I receive this error

> data-sly-set: None of the registered plugins can handle the
>   data-sly-set block element.

I am indeed using the data-sly-set property like so

```
<sly data-sly-set.index="${mylist.count}"></sly>
```

And it does work on my local instance it just fails validation when packaging it.

I noticed that htl-maven-plugin was on version 1.0.6 if that is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the version of htl-maven-plugin was too old. I resolved this issue by going into pom.xml and added

`<version>1.3.4-1.4.0</version>`

underneath

```
<artifactId>htl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

It ended up looking like this

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
   <artifactId>htl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.4-1.4.0</version>
</plugin>
```

After that it I ran

```
mvn -PautoInstallPackage clean install
```

and it built successfully. I also ran

`mvn versions:display-plugin-updates`

earlier to force it to update but I'm not entirely sure if that was necessary.